# can in angular call parent componet function when click any button on child component?

Tags: angular

I create custom angular grid view as a child compoent and need to use it in all parent componet

Every record on grid contains many actions ( edit - delete  )

I need when click edit button in child component fire business function in 
parent one

because I Grid Custom Control to be Global in all application

Comment: Please show us some code using [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you complete the [tour of heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial)? If you didn't, I advise you to start there before trying anything else

Answer (score 2):

Use `@Output` decorator to define output property

template

```
<button (click)="buttonClick()">My button</button>
```

component

```
@Output() doBusiness: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

buttonClick() {
    this.doBusiness.emit(...some data...);
}
```

parent template

```
<child-component (doBusiness)="doMyWork($event)"></child-component>
```

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event